# Dynamic request with requests of python

Tags: python, python-requests

do not know if I will be objective, ask for help.

I have a http request using python requests.

```
session = requests.Session()    
auth = session.post(url+'find.action', data=formData)
```

So far so good.

I need to do is:

In response to this request there is an action, a call to another url loaded and fired by a javascript GET type.

Question: How do I shoot one javascript firing another URL, until the response be loaded?

Only with this can load the response validated.

Exemplo of javacript

```
new Ajax.Request(url+'validate.action?indice=0&documento=123455&type=post&random='+Math.random(), 
                { method:'get',
                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

I was able to solve using PyQT.

Worked fine.

Follows down to who has the same question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU